# How two tables can be connected in Excel using array formula?

Tags: excel, array-formulas, sumifs

[image]

I have two tables B3:C8 and F3:G5. I want to sum those values in column B which belongs to a vehicle whose type is 1. At this example Car or Motor. (In the real example the tables are much bigger.)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need an array?

In column H next to the second table put this formula

```
=IF($F3=1,SUMIF($C:$C,G3,$B:$B),"")
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Erjon, you pointed me to the right direction. I need a single formula, which is

=SUM(IF(F3:F5=1;SUMIFS(B3:B8;C3:C8;G3:G5);0))